# libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, libxml2, yum

I am using Centos in which i had removed libxml2 accidentally now it was showing the folling error as follows

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

```
libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Jun 18 2012, 08:55:31)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall libxml2 by running `sudo yum install libxml2`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to reinstall the libxml2 package. Since yum is currently broken on your system, you will need to obtain the libxml2 package by another means, such as using `yumdownloader` on another (working) system or by visiting your repositories website or from one of the CentOS mirrors. For example here is a link to [the CentOS5.9 libxml2 rpm for i386](http://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/centos/5.9/updates/i386/RPMS/libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.2.i386.rpm) .